# On Click event on lat/long map point in highmaps

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, highmaps

I am working with highmaps and got stuck to get the click event on mappoint on lat/long map .

Is there any API reference for the same to apply onclick event on map point ?

code

```
// Initiate the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic lat/lon demo'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>Lat: {point.lat}, Lon: {point.lon}'
    },

    series: [{
        // Use the gb-all map with no data as a basemap
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/gb/gb-all'],
        name: 'Basemap',
        borderColor: '#A0A0A0',
        nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3)',
        showInLegend: false
    }, {
        name: 'Separators',
        type: 'mapline',
        data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/gb/gb-all'], 'mapline'),
        color: '#707070',
        showInLegend: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        // Specify points using lat/lon
        type: 'mappoint',
        name: 'Cities',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        data: [{
            name: 'London',
            lat: 51.507222,
            lon: -0.1275
        }, {
            name: 'Birmingham',
            lat: 52.483056,
            lon: -1.893611
        }, {
            name: 'Leeds',
            lat: 53.799722,
            lon: -1.549167
        }, {
            name: 'Glasgow',
            lat: 55.858,
            lon: -4.259
        }, {
            name: 'Sheffield',
            lat: 53.383611,
            lon: -1.466944
        }, {
            name: 'Liverpool',
            lat: 53.4,
            lon: -3
        }, {
            name: 'Bristol',
            lat: 51.45,
            lon: -2.583333
        }, {
            name: 'Belfast',
            lat: 54.597,
            lon: -5.93
        }, {
            name: 'Lerwick',
            lat: 60.155,
            lon: -1.145,
            dataLabels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 5,
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            }
        }]
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon/

Above is the example from highmaps , but i did not get any API reference to achieve click event on lat/long mappoint.

Thanks

Comment: Use point click event (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/07kwxwo9/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check reference [plotOptions.series.point.events.click](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.point.events.click)

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var text = '<b>Clicked point</b><br>Series: ' + this.series.name +
              '<br>Point: ' + this.name + ' (lat: ' + this.lat + ' lon:' + this.lon + ')',
              chart = this.series.chart;
            if (!chart.clickLabel) {
              chart.clickLabel = chart.renderer.label(text, 0, 250)
                .css({
                  width: '180px'
                })
                .add();
            } else {
              chart.clickLabel.attr({
                text: text
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fh7odom4/1/) demo